# How to handle "non-https" (http) sites in https TYPO3 backend

Tags: apache, ssl, typo3, httpd.conf

We run a TYPO3 multidomain system and added https support to our TYPO3 domain `[typo3domain]`. All other domains still run without https support (http only).

https works perfect for [typo3domain].
Redirect of all non https request to TYPO3 backend (lockSSL) works perfect as well. `[typo3domain]/typo3` redirects automatically to `https://[typo3domain]/typo3`

Now our problem:
If a editor [domain1] edits some content on `https://[typo3domain]/typo3` and goes to `page -> view page` then `https://[domain1]` is called, but this does not work (invalid certificate), because [domain1] is a non ssl domain.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the preview domain in the root page TSconfig of the non-https sites, including the protocol:

```
TCEMAIN.previewDomain = http://domain1
```

More on this option can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceMain.html#previewdomain